# Laravel Datatables Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, table-relationships, yajra-datatable

Hi Guys I have a small problem about yajra package. I want to show belongsto relation ship id->name but I couldn't do it. I try more then 100 variables. I don't understand how to show it.

```
This is my APIController


$alinislar = Alinis::all();

$turlar = Tur::with('turlar')->select('turlar.*');

return Datatables::of($alinislar, $turlar)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($alinislar) {
        return
            '<a href="tur/' . $alinislar->alinis_id . '/edit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">Düzenle</a>' .
            '<a href="tur/destroy/' . $alinislar->alinis_id . '" class="btn btn-danger" >Sil</a>';
    })
    ->make(true);
```

and my js code is

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script src="{{asset('adminsrc/global/vendor/datatables.net-bs4/dataTables.bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Turkish.json"
            },
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('alinis.getir')}}',
            columns: [
                {data: "alinis_adi", name: "alinis_adi"},
                {data: "tur_id", name: ""},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]

        });
    });


</script>
```

Tur Model

```
public function alinislar(){

    return $this->hasMany(Alinis::class);

}
```

Alinis Model

```
  public function Tur(){

    return $this->belongsTo(Tur::class);

}
```

I want to add tur_id -> name. id works properly but How can I do that ? Please be specific. I checked all yajra issues. I couldn't do it..

Comment: you question is not clear, what's the relationship of your model? what relationship you want to get?

Comment: Share your model file.

Comment: I added Models. Hope you can give me an answer.